# select from @variable how to use variable after from

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, dynamic-sql

I have a query that should get results from several databases located in 2 different servers:

- I created a linked server to connect to the second server.
- I was able to loop databases located under one server, my problem is that I cannot get the second server where the other database "NCHKS" is located.
- I tried to declare a variable for server name and call it after from in select but I couldn't place the correct syntax

Below is my query:

```
 declare @dbname varchar(max)
 --select @dbname = '"NCHLB", "NCHDU", "NCHCY", "NCCH", "NCHOS", "NCHUK", 
--"AFRNW" , "NCAFR", "NCTRK", "NCCPI", "NCIOL", "NCDLM", "NCHOL", "NCHCL", 
--"NMISL", "NCHMP"'
select @dbname = '"NCHKS"'
declare @sql varchar(max)

declare @servername varchar(max) 
set @servername = iif (@dbname = '"NCHKS"','[SERVER2]','[SERVER1]')
--select @servername


select @sql = isnull(@sql,'') 
  + case when @sql is null then '' else ' union all ' end
  + 'SELECT  ''' + db.name + ''' as [DB Name],  [year1], [jrnentry]
          FROM  ' + @servername + '.' + db.name + '.dbo.PK_OPEN_AA_DIST A 
CROSS JOIN  ' + @servername + '.'  + db.name + '.dbo.MC40000 AS mc

          Union ALL

          SELECT ''' + db.name + ''' as [DB Name], [year1], [jrnentry]

           FROM  ' + @servername + '.' + db.name + '.dbo.PK_HIST_AA_DIST  
 A CROSS JOIN  ' + @servername + '.'  + db.name + '.dbo.MC40000 AS mc'

 from   [SERVER2].Master.sys.databases db
 where @dbname  like '%"' + db.name + '"%'

select @sql = '
Select  [DB Name],  JRNENTRY
                       from (' + @sql + ') as AllData

                       order by YEAR1, JRNENTRY'

 execute (@sql)
```

What I am not able to do is in to replace SERVER2 or SERVER1 in the below syntax to a SERERNAME variable

```
from   [SERVER2].Master.sys.databases db
```

it should by something similar to:

```
from @servername.Master.sys.databases db
```

where @servername is a declared variable of the servername based on database name
appreciate your assistance.

Comment: If you must do it that way you will need [dynamic SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: String literals don't use double quotes. The @servername logic should be in the outer level code.

Comment: Ok, I see the quotes are used for database names. I don't see that you need them though.

Comment: @DaleBurrell can you update my query adding the script of dynamic SQL, since I am not an SQL expert :)